# Append to asp.net ListView not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net, listview, signalr

I use SignalR to receive data every few seconds. When append the data to simple:

```
<ul id="messages"></ul>
```

they are showed, but when I try to append them to ListView:

```
<asp:listview id="logListView" runat="server" itemplaceholderid="itemPlaceHolder"   clientidmode="Static" enableviewstate="False">
            <layouttemplate>
                <ul id="logUl">
                    <li runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder"></li>
                </ul>
            </layouttemplate>
            <itemtemplate>
                <li><span ><%#Container.DataItem.ToString() %></span></li>
            </itemtemplate>
</asp:listview>
```

then nothing is showed. Here is my jquery code which appends data:

```
chatHub.client.send = function (message) {
            var encodedSymbol1 = $('<div />').text(message.Symbol1).html();
            var encodedSymbol2 = $('<div />').text(message.Symbol2).html();

            $('#logUl').append('<li>' + encodedSymbol1 + " , " + encodedSymbol2 + '</li>');//NOT WORKING
            $('#messages').append('<li>' + encodedSymbol1 + " , " + encodedSymbol2 + '</li>');//OK
        };
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like append using jQuery was ok. ListView was not rendered because datasource was not assigned.
This helped:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var myLog = new List<string>();
            myLog.Add(string.Format("{0} - Logging Started", DateTime.UtcNow));

            logListView.DataSource = myLog;
            logListView.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The id `logUl` would be changed in generated html, try using [Attribute Contains Selector [name*="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('[id*=logUl]').append('<li>' + encodedSymbol1 + " , " + encodedSymbol2 + '</li>');
```

Comment: Tried but with no luck. Added quotes to logUl: "logUl" but no succeed too. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Huh, strange thing: I searched generated html and there are no elements with names like: listview, logListView, logUl, itemPlaceHolder. The area where shoud be related code is just empty.

Comment: Searched using Debugging in Developer Tools and as advised searchech using Edit->Find. Nothing. <asp:listview id="logListView" is not added to generated html code at all even as UnorderedList or other element, just empty space in place where some code shoud be. I have <asp:GridView below the ListView and the grdView is showed. No idea why ListView output is not generated.